# How to resize a Qwidget to bigger than default size

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

I have a problem with the size of widget in Qt. I am Using it to display some game pictures, but it doesn't fit in there, it just adds two scrollbars, which is not what I need.

I tried this:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    this->maze = new MazeGUI();

    QHBoxLayout * layout = new QHBoxLayout;
    layout->addWidget(this->maze);
    ui->widget->setLayout(layout);
    ui->widget->resize(800, 600);
}
```

It works when I use "ui->widget->resize(200, 200);" which is smaller than some default size. But when I try some bigger number like in example, it doesn't work, just sets the QWidget size to the default size.

Edit: Maybe this will help solving the problem.

```
   <widget class="QWidget" name="widget" native="true">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>50</x>
      <y>10</y>
      <width>511</width>
      <height>361</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="sizePolicy">
     <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Expanding">
      <horstretch>0</horstretch>
      <verstretch>0</verstretch>
     </sizepolicy>
    </property>
   </widget>
```

Comment: Also tried to make it bigger in the .ui file but does not work also.

Comment: Which widget contains the scroll area?

Comment: I just clicked that I want widget in the designer in Qt creator and add it on the formular, which is I think MainWindow, but resizing the MainWindow does not cause any problems, just the widget on it.

Comment: What happens when you try `ui->widget->setMinimumSize(800, 600);`?

Comment: solved, I was resizing wrong widget ... Find out that I changed its background color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have to set minimum width/height before resizing. Check this [link.](http://groakat.wordpress.com/2012/02/28/qwidget-resize-in-constructor-has-no-effect/)

Comment: I was trying this: 
ui->widget->setMaximumSize(1000, 1000);
ui->widget->setMinimumSize(400, 400);
but it does not work.

Comment: Setting size policy in .ui file on widget to Expanding is not helping at all.

Comment: @Whitedracke What do you mean by *it doesnt' work*? If you set a minimum size to a widget, that should be the minimum size of the widget.

Comment: I ment, that the set (min/max) is not causing any errors, but the resize after it is still not working.

Comment: @Whitedracke Are you saying that it doesn't obey the minimum and maximum size?